# Takes so much time to create PDF report

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have been using tcpdf to export my data to pdf , 1st i got an error saying allocated memory is not enough, then i increased the memory size using `ini_set()`. Now it takes about 5 minutes to generate the PDF file,pdf file contains 19 pages of data. Can any one suggest me how to optimize the performance? 
Can i use a software like PDFCreator and print the report with out exporting the file?

Comment: Probably need to see what you are doing? Handling lots of images -they take time and memory? Try compressing images first. Got any loops in those 19 pages? Does it take as long if you just "echo" the same amoutn of data as opposed to pumping into PDF?

Comment: Data doesn't contain images,When i just echo the the data it only takes about 4 Seconds, but when i export to pdf it takes nearly 5 minuets,

Comment: As opposed to open in PDF save as a file. How long does that take? Then how longto open the file in PDF? (Will determine where the problem lies)

Comment: I used this to save the file, 
$pdf->Output('sandbox/pdf/example.pdf', 'F');
but seems it takes time same as before.

Comment: Next question, can you put "echo LINE . time() . '
';" in various parts of your content generation and see where the large gaps lie? See if there is any particular function call that's taking longer than others?

Answer (score 4):

### Best practices

Did you check the [performance best practices](https://tcpdf.org/docs/performances/) on the TCPDF website?

There are some simple optimisations that you could make, like

> - If you are not using the Thai language, edit the config/tcpdf_config.php file and set the K_THAI_TOPCHARS constant to false;
> - By default TCPDF enables font subsetting to reduce the size of embedded Unicode TTF fonts, this process, that is very slow and requires a lot of memory, can be turned off using setFontSubsetting(false) method;
> - Use core fonts instead of embedded fonts whenever possible;

### Analysis

A really thorough way of analysing performance problems (this is called [Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)) in PHP is using *xdebug*. It will log all your function calls and the time they take. These log files can then be visualised. I recommend Webgrind as an interface for this, [here's how to get started](https://code.google.com/p/webgrind/wiki/Installation).

It is an initial effort to set it up and learn how to understand the data, but then it's a valuable tool for performance optimisation.